# Infinite recursive types in Coq (for Bananas and Lenses)

Tags: coq, recursion-schemes

I'd like to see a Coq version of the Bananas, Lenses, etc. They are built up in the excellent series of blog posts at [sumtypeofway Introduction to Recursion schemes](https://blog.sumtypeofway.com/an-introduction-to-recursion-schemes/)

However, the blog post is in Haskell, which permits infinite non-terminating recursion, and thus is perfectly content with the `Y` combinator. Which Coq isn't.

In particular, the definitions depend on the type

```
newtype Term f = In { out :: f (Term f) }
```

which builds inifinite types  `f (f (f (f ...)))`.  `Term f`  permits very pretty and succinct definitions for catamorphisms, paramorphisms, anamorphisms, etc., using the Term family of types.

Trying to port this to Coq as

```
Inductive Term f : Type := {out:f (Term f)}.
```

gives me the expected

```
Error: Non strictly positive occurrence of "Term" in "f (Term f) -> Term f".
```

*Q: What would be a good way to formalize the above Haskell Term type in Coq?*

Above `f` is of type `Type->Type`, but perhaps it is too general, and there could be some way to restrict us to inductive types such that each application of `f` is decreasing?

Perhaps someone has already implemented the recursion schemes from [Banans, Lenses, Envelopes](https://research.utwente.nl/en/publications/functional-programming-with-bananas-lenses-envelopes-and-barbed-w) in Coq?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the popular solution is to encode functors as ["containers"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Container_(type_theory)), the intro of this paper is a good starting point: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.08059.pdf The idea is much older (the paper means to give a self-contained explanation), and you can chase the references from that paper, but what I found in a cursory search can be hard to follow if you're not familiar with type theory or category theory.

In short, instead of `Type -> Type`, we use the following type:

```
Set Implicit Arguments.
Set Contextual Implicit.

Record container : Type := {
  shape : Type;
  pos : shape -> Type;
}.
```

where roughly, if you imagine a "base functor" `F` of a recursive type `Fix F`, `shape` describes the constructors of `F`, and for each constructor, `pos` enumerates the "holes" in it. So the base functor of `List`

```
data ListF a x
  = NilF       -- no holes
  | ConsF a x  -- one hole x
```

is given by this container:

```
Inductive list_shape a :=
  | NilF : list_shape a
  | ConsF : a -> list_shape a.

Definition list_pos a (s : list_shape a) : Type :=
  match s with
  | NilF    => False (* no holes *)
  | ConsF _ => True  (* one hole x *)
  end.

Definition list_container a : container := {|
  shape := list_shape a;
  pos := fun s => list_pos s;
|}.
```

The point is that this container describes a strictly positive functor:

```
Inductive ext (c : container) (a : Type) : Type := {
  this_shape : shape c;
  this_rec : pos c this_shape -> a;
}.

Definition listF a : Type -> Type := ext (list_container a).
```

so instead of `Fix f = f (Fix f)`, the fixpoint construction can take a container:

```
Inductive Fix (c : container) : Type := MkFix : ext c (Fix c) -> Fix c.
```

Not all functors can be encoded as containers (the continuation functor being a prime example) but you don't often see them used with `Fix`.

Full gist: https://gist.github.com/Lysxia/21dd5fc7b79ced410b129f31ddf25c12

Comment: Which version of Coq do you use? I'm unable to feed the `Inductive ext ...`. I'm using 8.9.1.

Comment: Sorry, I just wrote it straight into SO without trying to compile it. `a` should be a parameter like `c`.

Comment: thanks for this - I have tried to read up on this, but could you please show how one would implement i.e. `fmap`  that operates on containers instead of arbitrary functors? I've not managed to do that...

Comment: Ok, I have a version of `fmap` now, but I had to change `list_shape` to have two holes for `ConsF` (I need a hole for the tail to be able to recurse).  Anyway, I think your answer is the way to go, so I'll mark it as accepted.  Thanks for your quick answer and clear explanation.  I might add a link to a gist here for (my own) reference later.